# Is there a way to dynamically determine the vhdSize flag?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, vhd, msix

I am using the MSIX manager tool to convert a `*.msix` (an application installer) to a `*.vhdx` so that it can be mounted in an Azure virtual machine. One of the flags that the tool requires is `-vhdSize`, which is in megabytes. This has proven to be problematic because I have to guess what the size should be based off the MSIX. I have ran into numerous creation errors due to too small of a `vhdSize`.

I could set it to an arbitrarily high value in order to get around these failures, but that is not ideal. Alternatively, guessing the correct size is an imprecise science and a chore to do repeatedly.

Is there a way to have the tool dynamically set the `vhdSize`, or am I stuck guessing a value that is both large enough to accommodate the file, but not too large as to waste disk space? Or, is there a better way to create a `*.vhdx` file?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-virtual-desktop/simplify-msix-image-creation-with-the-msixmgr-tool/m-p/2118585

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an MSIX Hero app that could select a size for you, it will automatically check how big the uncompressed files are, add an extra buffer for safety (currently double the original size), and round it to the next 10MB. Reference from https://msixhero.net/documentation/creating-vhd-for-msix-app-attach/